# what actually JAX-WS is?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I need to work on webservice project. So going through book to cover the basics of webservice project. But these are questions I am struggling with:-

1.Java API for XML Web Services(JAX-WS):- JAX-WS is nothing but just a java programming language API for creating web services which is now a part of core java starting from version 6 (though originally developed as part of Java Web Services Development Pack). Is it right?

2.All other webservices framework whether it is metro, jersey, glassfish uses the JAX-WS internally. Is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Q:** 1.Java API for XML Web Services(JAX-WS):- JAX-WS is nothing but just a java programming language API for creating web services which is now a
>   part of core java starting from version 6 (though originally developed
>   as part of Java Web Services Development Pack). Is it right?

It is correct, JAX-WS is an application programming interfaces (API). That API, together with the JAX-WS reference implementation ([JAX-WS RI](https://jax-ws.java.net/), RI = reference implementation) is a part of JDK since version 6. To extend a little bit, JAX-WS 2.0 is included in JDK 6 from the beginning, JAX-WS 2.1 comes with JDK 6u4, and you will find JAX-WS 2.2 in JDK 7 (see [this link](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.7/docs/ch02.html#running-on-top-of-jdk-6)).

> **Q:** 2.All other webservices framework whether it is metro, jersey, glassfish uses the JAX-WS internally. Is it correct?

Strictly speaking, Metro doesn't "use" JAX-WS, but includes already mentioned JAX-WS reference implementation. Jersey included JAX-RS implementation, and Glassfish is not a Web-service framework, but an application server. Glassfish comes with the complete Metro distribution.

Comment: Thanks Miljen. From net I came to know that, JAX-WS RI is a reference implementation of the JAX-WS specification. But then what is meaning of here 
 reference implementation ? Is it just POC done using JAX-WS so that other people can refer it or its some pluggable component which we can directly use?

Comment: @emilly You are welcome. Meaning of reference implementation is some kind of standard, i.e. it covers (implements) all parts of JAX-WS specification. It is definitely not a POC since it's included in JDK and used everywhere :) It is also a core of Metro framework that is used in many places, starting from Glassfish (where it is integrated into), to standalone implementations plugged elsewhere (e.g. in Tomcat, see [this link](https://metro.java.net/1.2/docs/install.html))

Answer (score 1):

JAX-WS is a Web Services framework that provides tools and infrastructure to develop Web Services solutions for the end users and middleware developersJAX-WS stands for Java API for XML Web Services. JAX-WS is a technology for building web services and clients that communicate using XML. JAX-WS allows developers to write message-oriented as well as RPC-oriented web services. 
In JAX-WS, a web service operation invocation is represented by an XML-based protocol such as SOAP. The SOAP specification defines the envelope structure, encoding rules, and conventions for representing web service invocations and responses. These calls and responses are transmitted as SOAP messages (XML files) over HTTP.

There is another type of web-service, which is called RESTful.RESTful web services are built to work best on the Web. Representational State Transfer (REST) is an architectural style that specifies constraints, such as the uniform interface, that if applied to a web service induce desirable properties, such as performance, scalability, and modifiability, that enable services to work best on the Web. In the REST architectural style, data and functionality are considered resources and are accessed using Uniform Resource Identifiers (URIs), typically links on the Web. The resources are acted upon by using a set of simple, well-defined operations. The REST architectural style constrains an architecture to a client/server architecture and is designed to use a stateless communication protocol, typically HTTP. In the REST architecture style, clients and servers exchange representations of resources by using a standardized interface and protocol.

Genrally JAX-RS is used for developing RESTful web services. JAX-RS is a Java programming language API designed to make it easy to develop applications that use the REST architecture. The JAX-RS API uses Java programming language annotations to simplify the development of RESTful web services. Developers decorate Java programming language class files with JAX-RS annotations to define resources and the actions that can be performed on those resources. JAX-RS annotations are runtime annotations; therefore, runtime reflection will generate the helper classes and artifacts for the resource. A Java EE application archive containing JAX-RS resource classes will have the resources configured, the helper classes and artifacts generated, and the resource exposed to clients by deploying the archive to a Java EE server.

Different frameworks uses either JAX-WS or JAX-RS. Jersey uses JAX-RS and Metro uses JAXWS.